Paging 3 is not loading next Page
Hi I have been trying to fetch Youtube list,  first i passed empty page , the data was perfectly fetched ,  but after that paging library is not fetching any data
  class RemotePagingSource constructor(private val listSection : PageListSection,
   private val  youtubeClient: YoutubeClient
) : PagingSource<String, Video>() {


override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<String, Video>): String? {



    val key =  state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
        state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey }


    return key }

val coroutineScope =  CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<String>): LoadResult<String, Video> {

    return try {

        val nextKey: String = if(params is Append) params.key else ""
        val pageSize =  params.loadSize

        val youtube = coroutineScope.async {

            Log.i("RemotePagingSource" , "Thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            youtubeClient.youtubeApi(nextKey , pageSize)}.await()

        Log.i("RemotePagingSource" , "RemotePaging  Page Sizd  ${pageSize}   Next Page ${youtube.nextPageToken}    Thread   ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

        LoadResult.Page(
            data = youtube.items ,
            prevKey = youtube.prevPageToken,
            nextKey = youtube.nextPageToken)

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    }


}

}
here is code for MainActivity for Compose Ui
@Composable
private fun PagingData(){
val youtubeList =   mainViewModel.youtubeApi().collectAsLazyPagingItems()

LazyColumn(modifier= Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .background(Color.White)) {

    items(youtubeList.itemCount){
        Box(modifier= Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    }



}

}
